# Isn't Prometheus with replicas and persistent volume already HA?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have been exploring a lot of options to make our Prometheus set up a high available one. 
I have boiled it down to two so far:
1. promxy - https://github.com/jacksontj/promxy (For ease & simplicity)
2. Thanos - https://thanos.io/getting-started.md/ ( For its uber - querier)

However, on bare metal, I can still have 2 instances of Prometheus and set up either of the above two to have HA and scalable Prometheus.

But on Kubernetes, where I have 2 replicas of Prometheus running with persistent volume and exposed over NodePort , isn't that already a HA solution ?

PS: I am setting up Prometheus using the coreos Prometheus operator

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having multiple instances of Prometheus and Alertmanager, if configured correctly (e.g. have a mesh for the Alertmanager instances to avoid duplicate alerts) is a HA setup. It doesn't matter if it's bare metal or within a replica set in k8s.

Have not used CoreOS's prometheus-operator myself but as far as I can tell it sets up the mesh for multiple Alertmanager instances.

*Note: this has nothing to do with scaling. The different Prom/AM instances are for redundancy, it achieves HA but doesn't make the whole setup able to handle more metrics than whatever the limit would be for an individual prometheus instance.*

Comment: The note in this answer is everything.

Comment: Think the key is HA of prometheus DB is easy but you will need to handle dedup on the alert-manager side since each prom will push data instead of being read.